# stuck with array_merge, need specific key value arrangement inside foreach loop

Tags: php

I've following PHP code:

```
$age = array_merge($age,array(get_user_meta($comment->user_id, 'wsl_user_age', true)));
```

This produces:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 26
    [1] => 
    [2] => 18
    [3] => 28
    [4] => 22
    [5] => 21
    [6] => 26
    [7] => 
    [8] => 
    [9] => 
    [10] => 
    [11] => 
    [12] =>
    [13] =>
    [14] =>
    [15] =>
    [16] =>
    [17] =>
    [18] =>
    [19] =>
    [20] =>
)
```

What I'd like to have is 26 18 etc as keys. And values number of times it repeats, in essence duplicate count.

I tried:

```
$age = array_merge($age,array(get_user_meta($comment->user_id, 'wsl_user_age', true)=> ""))
```

But this produced absolute nonsense.

What should I try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for `array_count_values`

```
$cnt_array = array_count_values($your_array);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($cnt_array);
```

Ref: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

Comment: Great, that's useful. But before I get there, I need to form my array in a good way first. So how can I get [26] => 1 structure in my foreach?

Comment: Check my answer it will return you something like : array([26]=>2,[28]=>1, .....)

Answer (score 0):

Here is something you might be looking for http://codepad.org/RDUhltQ7

have a look

Answer (score 0):

```
$foo = Array
(   26,
    18,
    28,
    22,
    21,
    26,
    '',
    ''
);

$foo = array_filter($foo);
$foo = array_count_values($foo);

print_r($foo);
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a1875256f4680b06b9d909bdb3329cfcd64d44de